# windows forms application - how to make the tabs in a tab control get full width?

Tags: winforms, user-interface, tabs

So i'am working with tabControl in windows forms application and i want to make the tabs get full width regardless whether the application window is maximized or not.
When the window isn't maximized everything appears great:
[image: non-maximized window]

But when the window gets maximized the tabs doesn't get the full width:
[image: maximized window]

Is there any known way to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in some way by modifying the ItemSize property as described bellow, else you'd have to draw the tab page selectors yourself.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tabControl1.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;
        tabControl1.ItemSize = new Size((tabControl1.Width / tabControl1.TabPages.Count) - 1, tabControl1.ItemSize.Height);
    }

     //Hook to form or parent container Resize event, either Resize or ResizeEnd.
     private void Form1_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        tabControl1.ItemSize = new Size((tabControl1.Width / tabControl1.TabPages.Count) - 1, tabControl1.ItemSize.Height);
     }
```

Comment: Sorry, you need a hook to SizeChanged event in order for it to work on Maximize and Minimize events.

Comment: doesn't work there is a 1 pixel overlap showing the arrows depending on the size of the tab control